# Android, Sprite animations

Tags: android, sprite

I am new to android and to this forum. I have a question:

I have managed to move a simple image without any animations. I also managed to do a sprite animation where i have a 4 images in one rectangle which i cut in to 4 pieces and show it on the screen each piece at a time.

this is what i do to cut through the bitmap image: canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, null);

Now how am i supposed to combine these 2. That is sprite animation should happen. The image also needs to move in the screen. what am i suppose to do. Please help me. I saw some tuts but i couldnot understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the coordinates in the `destRest` to point to the desired destination coordinates before drawing.

```
Rect destRect = new Rect(topLeftX, topLeftY, topLeftX + spriteWidth, topLeftY + spriteHeight);
```

Comment: The link is broken